# Missing hyphenation patterns in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, babel, hyphenation

I'm using `tlmgr` to manage packages, I have installed `babel-hungarian` and `hyphen-hungarian`, but hyphenation is not working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[hungarian]{babel}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

`xelatex` displays a warning (also, if I try to compile a larger document, hyphenation is definitely not working):

```
$ xelatex test.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
[...]
Package hungarian.ldf Warning: All Hungarian hyphenation= patterns missing.
(hungarian.ldf)                To make LaTeX hyphenate Hungarian words, please
(hungarian.ldf)                modify language.dat and rerun initex or texconfi
g.
[...]
```

I'm out of ideas, how can I fix hyphenation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You will save yourself a great deal of trouble if you install the full version of TeX Live.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a straw file added by the OP to the TeX system

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem, my TeX Live files were messed up, previously I've installed `magyar.ldf` manually, reinstalling TeX Live fixed the problem. Full version is not needed, I've selected only the needed package collections (including *Other European Languages*).